# Generate rig button greyed out

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm quite new to animation and I'm going to make my first walk cycle. I started by importing a character I got from sketchfab and it doesn't have any rig layers, but the button is greyed out. How come? Do I have to create my own armature?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is Mixamo Rig. To get the generate rig option active, you need to use Blender's own Rig called Rigify. From Edit go to Preference and from Addon you can active Rigify.

Comment: I have already done that. It's still greyed out. I tried to make my own armature, but when I apply the weights with ctrl+P the body parts become disaligned.

Comment: Please share your Blender file.

Comment: Rigify works either on its own metarig, or you have to add "rigify types" to your bones so that it can recognize the rig parts and generate a rig out of it.